# how to column names of excel sheet into list dynamically using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFileViaModel([FromForm] FileInputModel model)
{
    if (model == null || model.FileToUpload == null || model.FileToUpload.Length == 0)
        return Content("file not selected");

    var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", model.FileToUpload.FileName);

    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await model.FileToUpload.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Files");
}
```

This is my controller, but I want user to give excel sheet and
I need to get the columns dynamically from the user uploaded excel sheet.

Comment: Looks like you posted code how to get the file. But there is non for excel reading. And SO has plenty of information how to read Excel

Comment: you can use ExcelDataReader and ExcelDataReader.DataSet nuget packages for implementation ask here